# Future Lucy's right hand?

Tags: fairy-tail

In the manga, we see that future Lucy has no longer her right arm, but no context is given about how she lost it.

Does it has anything to do with Natsu of that timeline to be killed by a dragon ? How did she lose her right arm ?

Comment: I've searched the web and I can only find other discussions about that she maybe lost her arm, it is never specifically stated that she lost her arm. Seeing as how she didn't tell a lot about the future before dying to protect present lucy, we can only speculate how she lost her arm, I've read those chapters again just to be sure but it is never said. We can only wait for an answer of the mangaka

Comment: The only bold statement that I found was made on [Pixiv Dictionary (Japanese)](http://dic.pixiv.net/a/%E6%9C%AA%E6%9D%A5%E3%83%AB%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B7%E3%82%A3) that she lost her right arm **due to the dragon's attack (bite?)**. However, there's no reference to it (perhaps only implied from the known scenario). But true, it's never been mentioned anywhere officially.

Comment: Didn't read Fairy Tail, but that description of Lucy losing her right arm reminds me of this: http://fairytail.wikia.com/wiki/Lucy_and_Migi.

Answer (score 1):

In the episode where we see Fiore being destroyed and Lucy on the ground, we can clearly see that Lucy lost her right arm as the kingdom was being destroyed right before Natsu came to save her.

I believe it was due to the destruction of the city, something must have crushed her right arm and she had no other choice but to cut it off since she was alone.